# how to change only date while keeping the time in timestamp postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to change only the date part while retaining the time part untouched on postgresql datetime column?

2019-09-02 10:00:00

to

2019-10-26 10:00:00

Comment: add an interval. `select '2019-09-02 10:00:00'::timestamp + '54 days'::interval;`

Comment: please be more specific.

Comment: i want to update date of that entire column by not changing the time

Comment: That's what Jason's expression will do

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the logic you want to use.  If you want to add or subtract an interval, you can use:

```
select '2019-09-02 10:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 month 24 day'
```

If you want to directly specify the second date:

```
select '2019-10-26'::timestamp + ('2019-09-02 10:00:00'::timestamp)::time
```